# What does "Pai" or "PAI" mean in the context of a "Historique Espèces" spreadsheet in a securities account?

Tags: sens, finance

I am reading in a "Historique Espèces" spreadsheet of a securities account in Fortuneo.  It says:

[image]

(values and dates in the screenshot are made up.)

What does "Pai" or "PAI" mean in the context of a "Historique Espèces" spreadsheet in a securities account?

Comment: @LaurentS. Thanks for the correction (was a typo)

Comment: Réponse [ici](https://societegenerale.nc/fr/entreprises/investissements/pret-aide-linvestissement-pai/) **Prêt Aidé à l’Investissement**. In the context of a school PAI is *projet d'accueil individualisé*.

Comment: @None thanks, interesting, do you understand why Prêt Aidé à l’Investissement would be listed in Historique Espèces in the securities account of an individual holding a few stocks?

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond the scope of French Language. You could try the question on money.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @LaurentS. I fixed the typo in the screenshot.

Comment: @None Sounds good: [Why would "Prêt Aidé à l’Investissement" yield some money to the shareholders?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/121042/5656)